# Solving $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-3x}-1}$ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus

Without L'Hopital:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-3x}-1}$$

Rationalize:

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-3x}-1}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1-3x}+1}{\sqrt{1-3x}+1}$$

$$\frac{x\cdot(\sqrt{1-3x}+1)}{(1-3x)-1}$$

This will still yield $\frac{0}{0}$. Maybe I should now try variable substitution to eliminate the root. Let

$$w^2 = 1-3x$$

So

$$w\to 1$$

Therefore

$$\lim_{w\to1}\frac{x\cdot(\sqrt{w^2}+1)}{(1-3x)-1} = \lim_{w\to1}\frac{x\cdot(w+1)}{(1-3x)-1}$$

We find that

$$x = \frac{1-w^2}{3}$$

So

$$\lim_{w\to1}\frac{\left( \frac{1-w^2}{3}\right)\cdot(w+1)}{\left(1-3\left( \frac{1-w^2}{3}\right)\right)-1}$$

$$\lim_{w\to1}\frac{\left( \frac{1-w^2}{3}\right)\cdot(w+1)}{\left(1-3+3w^2\right)-1}$$

This will still evaluate to $\frac{0}{0}$.

I just usted the two methods that I always use to calculate limits. Rationalize/factorize and variable substitution. I'm not supposed to use L'Hopital.

**What did I do wrong**, and how should I have done it?

Comment: After the rationalize step, you should cancel the $x$ terms...  I'm thinking you'll end up with something like $-\frac 23$?

Comment: Note that  $(1-3x)-1=-3x$.

Comment: Even for your second method, you can eliminate $(1-w^2)$ from the last step. And of course, $(1-w^2)$ is just $x$ times a constant in disguise.

Comment: Aa a general rule, after a rationalisation you should always *simplify*.

Comment: It's superfluous, but you also made a simplification mistake when going from the second-to-last expression to the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till here $$\lim_{w\to1}\frac{x\cdot(\sqrt{w^2}+1)}{(1-3x)-1} = \lim_{w\to1}\frac{x\cdot(w+1)}{(1-3x)-1}$$ is correct.

$$ $$ 
$$ $$
$$ $$

Then:
$$\lim_{w\to1}\frac{x\cdot(w+1)}{(1-3x)-1} = \lim_{w\to1} \frac{x\cdot(w+1)}{-3x}$$

$$ $$

Becuase of $$w\to1$$

$$ $$

$$ \lim_{w\to1} \frac{x\cdot(w+1)}{-3x} = \frac{2x}{-3x} = -\frac{2}{3} $$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-3x}-1}=-\frac13\left(\sqrt{1-3x}+1\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{1-3x}=1+h$. We know that when $x=0$ the LHS $=1 \Rightarrow h=0$

Then $1-3x=1+2h+h^2$

$-3x=2h+h^2$

$x=\frac{2h+h^2}{-3}$

The expression we want is $\frac x{\sqrt{1-3x}-1}=\frac {\frac{2h+h^2}{-3}}{1+h-1}=\frac{2+h}{-3}$.

As $h$ tends to $0$ this tends to $-\frac23$

Comment: what does "LHS" mean? Thanks for answering :)

Comment: @CAFosta LHS stands for left-hand side (and RHS for right-hand side).

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your post, you have
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-3x}-1}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1-3x}+1}{\sqrt{1-3x}+1}=\frac{x\cdot(\sqrt{1-3x}+1)}{(1-3x)-1}=\frac{\sqrt{1-3x}+1}{-3}$$
for all $x\leq 1/3$.
Hence
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-3x}-1}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1-3x}+1}{-3}.$$